# Copy TByteDynArray (array of byte) to string

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

How can I copy contents of a TByteDynArray variable to a string variable or even better, to a TMemoryStream?

Remy, thanks for your answer.

Well, I can't get it to work.
I'm doing this:
obtReferenciaPagamentoResponse.pdf is a TByteDynArray (array of byte) that comes throught a WebService call, that is referenced on the XSD like xsd:base64Binary.

```
procedure saveFile;
var
  LInput, LOutput: TMemoryStream;
  Id: Integer;
  Buff: AnsiString;
  //Buff: String;
begin
  LInput := TMemoryStream.Create;
  LOutput := TMemoryStream.Create;

  // Tried like this also
  //SetLength(Buff, Length(obtReferenciaPagamentoResponse.pdf));
  //Move(obtReferenciaPagamentoResponse.pdf[0], Buff[1],       Length(obtReferenciaPagamentoResponse.pdf));

  // Tried other charsets
  Buff := TEncoding.Ansi.GetString(obtReferenciaPagamentoResponse.pdf);

  LInput.Write(Buff[1], Length(Buff) * SizeOf(Buff[1]));
  LInput.Position := 0;

  TNetEncoding.Base64.Decode(LInput, LOutput);
  LOutput.Position := 0;
  LOutput.SaveToFile(SaveDialog2.FileName);

  LInput.Free;
  LOutput.Free;
end;
```

But the PDF file is saved incompleted, I guess, because is always corrupted on open.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`String` is an alias for [`UnicodeString`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.UnicodeString) since 2009.  As `UnicodeString` characters are now encoded in UTF-16, it does not make sense to copy raw bytes into a `(Unicode)String` unless the bytes are also encoded in UTF-16. In that case, you can simply use [`SetLength()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SetLength) to allocate the `String`'s length to the appropriate number of `Char`s and then [`Move()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Move) the raw bytes into the `String`'s allocated memory. Otherwise, use [`TEncoding.GetString()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding.GetString) instead to *decode* the bytes into a UTF-16 `String` using the appropriate charset.

As for `TMemoyStream`, it has a [`Write()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStream.Write) method for writing raw bytes into the stream.  Simply set its [`Position`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStream.Position) property to the desired offset and then write the bytes.

Comment: Ok, figure it out. Solved! Thanks!